# Generated texture will sometimes appear blank

Tags: materials

I am messing around I'm trying to create a material and I've noticed something very strange when using Generated texture coordinates. Sometimes when I assign the material to an object, the object will remain blank. Sometimes my material will appear, sometimes it doesn't, and I can't find any rhyme or reason as to why. This seems to be only happening when looking at it through Eevee, the materials (usually) show up fine in cycles.

Here is a picture showing what I mean, where I created a bunch of planes, assigned the exact same material to each of them, but some of them will randomly show as blank.

[image: Generated]

I'm a bit of a beginner at blender and I'm doing this in part because I'm trying to learn how things work. If for some reason I need to use Object or UV generation, I will, but really I am trying to understand if there is something about how I am using Generated that causes this, or if this is just a bug (which is what it seems like to me).

Comment: Could you upload the blend file? Just upload it here and copy the given text: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Hope this works. Here's the blend file:
[<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=dxMkW317" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/dxMkW317/)

Comment: Hm...all the materials are showing up on my screen. I guess it may just be a bug, or that your computer hasn't calculated all the textures yet, as it took a few seconds for the textures to show up.

Comment: That's frustrating but thanks for trying. If you see them all I guess it's a bug. Are you on 2.81?

Comment: Yeah, running on Win10